# R ggmap ggplot2 error “Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale”

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to mark airports in India on India map. My code is as follows:

```
library(ggmap)

library(ggplot2)

airports <- read.csv("C://Users//MEJA03514//Downloads//in-airports.csv", header=T)

map <- get_googlemap("India", zoom = 4)

points <- ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(x = longitude_deg, y = latitude_deg), data = airports, alpha = 0.5)

points
```

I downloaded the airports data file from: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/ourairports-ind

I am getting an error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

after I am combining `ggmap()` with `geom_point()` function. Can you please help me figure out what is the mistake in this code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that latitude and longitude are stored as numeric and not `factor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly for me with your code. But I was also able to reproduce your error: have a look at `airport` using `View(airport)` or `head(airport)` and you will notice that your data has in first row values that explain the variables (HXL tags). Make sure you download the data without these tags or remove them manually (but then you have to get data-types correct). If you check `str(airport)`, longitude and latitude should be `numeric`, not `character`.